# Collection.observeChanges added: callback is triggered on each 10 second poll

Tags: meteor

First I seed an Activities collection through a fixtures file in a server directory. The collection has many courses. Different courses may have the same 'topic' field.
I want to organize the presented list of courses by the topic field; so I first display a list of all the topics. To determine what topics are in the Activities database I use the courseTopics helper below.

Simplified for clarification

server/fixtures.js

```
  if Activities.find().count == 0 {
    acts= [ {type: 'course', topic: 'science'}, ....]
    _.each(acts, function(act) {
    Activities.insert(act);
    })
  }
```

client/activityList.coffee

```
 Template.topicsList.helpers
     courseTopics: ()->
         topicsList = []
         cLq = Activities.find({type: 'course'})
         handle = cLq.observeChanges({ 
         added: (id, user)->
             console.log "add to activities.", arguments 
         }); 
         cL = cLq.fetch()
         _.each cL, (c)->
             if _.indexOf(topicsList, c.definition.topic) is -1 {
               topicsList.push(c.definition.topic)
             }

         tL = _.map topicsList, (t) ->
             {topic: t}
```

My problem is that the entire course list is being invalidated; ... the cLq.observeChanges callback shows that the collection is responding to an event where each of the 'course' activity documents is being added anew every 10 seconds; apparently with the driver poll.

a grep on my directory tree only shows Activities.insert in the initial server fixtures file; and I don't know where to look to see what is triggering the repetitive 'add.' Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess the template is re-rendered, causing the courseTopics function to run again, so it's not a change to the collection. Can that be the problem?

Comment: Just an idea, not sure if itll help, but instead of calling the `.fetch()` method and altering your courses data have you considered using a transform (http://docs.meteor.com/#collections) instead? Reactivity works better with a cursor is given to handlebars as opposed to json data, especially with lists.

Comment: I just looked at doing a Collection transform /or Collection 'map' function; but then it seemed a collection 'reduce' like function with memoization would be needed.